# Compare products using a checkbox

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, products, compare

It seems too cumbersome for the user to have to wait for a page reload everytime they click on "add to compare" to add a product to a compare list and I wanted to change thelink with a checkbox and then add a button that will submit the list of products to compare and then send you to that page.

What is the best way to do this?

## Edit:

I will post the code I used so that someone else can use it in the future!

In each product I have a checkbox like this:

```
<input class="idcompare" type="checkbox" name="idcompare<?php echo $_product->getId();?>" value="<?php echo $_product->getId();?>">Compare
```

Then I have my form with the button that will send me to the compare page:

```
<form id="comparelist">
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Compare') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Compare') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
```

And my js that will change the action and submit the form! (not very elegant I know but it works):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#comparelist .button').click(function(){
            
            var i=0;
            var prdString="";

            var prdString = jQuery.map(jQuery(':checkbox:checked'), function(n, i){
                  return n.value;
            }).join(',');

            
            var url='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index').'items/'; ?>'+ prdString + '/uenc/';
            jQuery('#comparelist').attr('action', url);
            jQuery('#comparelist').submit();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to add a product to compare you need the following url:

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/items/' + productID + '/uenc/'
```

You can add multiple items to compare at the same time by creating a comma seperated string of the product id's.

It would look something like this:

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/items/10,23,456,8/uenc/'
```

Based on this information you can set this up with checkboxes by doing the following:

- create a `<form>`
- create checkboxes for each item you want to be able to compare
- set the `id` of each checkbox to the id of the product
- add some js to the onclick event of the checkbox that adds the `id` to a comma separated sring
- `onSubmit` have the `form action` go here:

  ```
  <?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>index.php/catalog/product_compare/index/items/' + prdString + '/uenc/'
  ```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I was on the right track studying the actual behaviour of magento but you just confirmed my thoughts.  In the demo I see the url as http://demo.magentocommerce.com/catalog/product_compare/index/items/16,119,120/uenc/aHR0cDovL2RlbW8ubWFnZW50b2NvbW1lcmNlLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvcy9zaGlydHMvaWQvNC8 what does that long string stand for? do I need it?

Comment: instead of `Mage::getBaseUr() . 'index.php...'` you can use `Mage::getUrl('catalog/product_compare/index').'items/' + prdString`. This way it doesn't mater if you set your website to use url rewrites or not.